# Golang unittest with *s3.S3 object

Tags: unit-testing, go

How should I unittest following piece of code. I was trying to use coutnerfiter to fake input "*s3.S3" object, but it's not working for me. I am new to coutnerfiter and Go, Can someone please help me on that.

```
func (l *listContentImp) ListS3Content(client *s3.S3) (bool, error) {

  listObj := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
    Bucket: aws.String(l.bucket),
  }

  var err error
  l.lObj, err = client.ListObjectsV2(listObj)
  if err != nil {
    return false, err
  }

  return true, nil
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a reference to the `s3.S3` struct. When using the AWS SDK for Go v1 you typically pass the services corresponding interface. For S3 this is [s3iface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3iface/).

The signature of your function would look like this:

```golang
func (l *listContentImp) ListS3Content(client s3iface.S3API) (bool, error)
```

Now every struct that you pass that implements at least one of the methods of `s3iface.S3API` will work.

At runtime you'll pass the proper service client, but in the unit tests you can just pass a mock:

```
type mock struct {
    s3iface.S3API

    output *s3.ListObjectsV2Output
    err     error
}

func (m mock) ListObjectsV2(*s3.ListObjectsV2Input) (*s3.ListObjectsV2Output, error) {
    return m.output, m.err
}
```

In your test you create the mock and pass it to your function:

```golang
func Test_ListObject(t *testing.T) {
    l := &listContentImp{...}
    m := mock{
        output: &s3.ListObjectsV2Output{...},
        err: nil
    }

    result, err := l.ListS3Content(m)
    
    [... add checks here...]
}
```

Comment: just to add, for all functions that return `*request.Request`, you will additionally need to mock the request object by adding mocked handlers to the `Handlers` field.